# Vertical Slider with dynamic sized images

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have an infinite vertical slider with static sized images that works perfectly

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/kTLWx/1/

However, the next slider I have to create the markup is a little different and all the images vary in height. Im trying to dynamically grab the height of the tags and move accordingly but I have not seem to find a working solution yet.

**Notes**
- I *CANNOT* change the HTML markup (its ugly I know but unfortunately I cannot change it), I cant add classes or IDS 
- The image widths are all the same, only the heights change

**HTML**

```
<div class="contain">
<a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
<span>
    <span>
        <a style="height: 90px;"><img /></a>
        <a style="background-color:blue; height: 69px;"><img /></a>
        <a style="height: 45px;"><img /></a>
        <a style="background-color:blue; height: 87px;"><img /></a>
        <a style="height: 43px;"><img /></a>
        <a style="background-color:blue; height: 72px;"><img /></a>
    </span>
</span>
<a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.contain span > span a:first-of-type').before($('.contain span > span a:last-of-type'));

$('#up').click(function() {
    var a = $('.contain span > span a:first-of-type'); 
    var height = a.clientHeight;

    movement = parseInt($('.contain span > span').css('top')) + height;  

   $('.contain span > span:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': movement }, 500, function () {
        $('.contain span > span a:first-of-type').before($('.contain span > span a:last-of-type'));
        $('.contain span > span').css({ 'top': height });
   });
});

$('#down').click(function() {
    var a = $('.contain span > span a:first-of-type'); 
    var height = a.clientHeight;

    movement = parseInt($('.contain span > span').css('top')) - height;  

   $('.contain span > span:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': movement }, 500, function () {
        $('.contain span > span a:last-of-type').after($('.contain span > span a:first-of-type'));
        $('.contain span > span').css({ 'top': height });
   });
});
```

Non-working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RPeLK/2/

Comment: thank you, very constructive

Comment: I mean, you should be able to fix at least this issue, right?!

Comment: yes that was something else before i changed it to $()

Comment: and then i guess: `var height = element.height();` ??? http://jsfiddle.net/RPeLK/3/

Comment: solved it............

Comment: @user934902 You did?  Can you post the fiddle with your answer?  I was working on this but if you solved it then I better stop..

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  Is that what you were going for?

Answer (score 1):

Well thought I would work on it just for fun.  I could not accomplish this using a `span` for the `link` container.  It was behaving oddly..  The `overflow:hidden` does not seem to work very good on a span element. But it worked when changing it to a div.

jQuery

```
$('.contain span > div a:first-of-type').before($('.contain span > div a:last-of-type'));
$('.contain span > div').css('top','-'+$('.contain span > div a:first-of-type').height()+'px');

$('#up').click(function() {
    var a = $('.contain span > div a:first-of-type'); 
    var height = a.height();
    movement = parseInt($('.contain span > div').css('top')) + height;     
   $('.contain span > div:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': movement }, 500, function () {
        $('.contain span > div a:first-of-type').before($('.contain span > div a:last-of-type'));
        height = $('.contain span > div a:first-of-type').height();
        $('.contain span > div').css({ 'top': '-'+height+'px' });
   });
});

$('#down').click(function() {
    var a = $('.contain span > div a:nth-child(2)'); 
    var height = a.height();
    movement = parseInt($('.contain span > div').css('top')) - height;  
   $('.contain span > div:not(:animated)').animate({ 'top': movement }, 500, function () {
        $('.contain span > div a:last-of-type').after($('.contain span > div a:first-of-type'));
        height = $('.contain span > div a:first-of-type').height();
        $('.contain span > div').css({ 'top': '-'+height+'px' });
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="contain">
<a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
<span>
    <div>
        <a style="height: 90px;background-color:green;"><img /></a>
        <a style="background-color:blue; height: 69px;"><img /></a>
        <a style="height: 45px;background-color:green;"><img /></a>
        <a style="background-color:blue; height: 87px;"><img /></a>
        <a style="height: 43px;background-color:green;"><img /></a>
        <a style="background-color:blue; height: 72px;"><img /></a>
    </div>
</span>
<a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.contain span { 
    display: block;height: 150px; border: 1px solid #d8d8d8; width: 50px; 
    margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative;
}
.contain span > div { 
    list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; border:none; 
    /*top: -?px; Needs to be dynamic based on first img*/
}
.contain span > div a { width: 100%;}

a { display: block; width: 50px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/RPeLK/4/

Comment: @user934902 Can I please get some feedback on my answer.  Or can you post your answer and mark it as accepted?   Thanks